# Unable to access NSF file using Python code - 'Notes error: Could not open the ID file'

Tags: python, lotus-notes

I am new to Python programming. I am trying to access my IBM notes .NSF file using Python code.

Here is my code.

```
import win32com.client
import pywintypes
import getpass

def main():
    # Get credentials
    mailServer = '' 
    mailPath = "path to nsf file"



    mailPassword = 'IBM Notes Password'
    # Connect
    notesSession = win32com.client.Dispatch('Lotus.NotesSession')



    notesSession.Initialize(mailPassword)
    notesDatabase = notesSession.GetDatabase(mailServer, mailPath)

    # Get a list of folders
    folder = notesDatabase.GetView('$Inbox')
    document = folder.GetFirstDocument()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

If I run the above code, I am getting the below error.
com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'NotesSession', 'Notes error: Could not open the ID file', None, 0, -2147217504), None)

Comment: Do you have the Notes Client installed and set up? Otherwise your python code will not work as it needs a configured Notes Client with known user id on the same machine.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Thank you @TorstenLink for your response. Yes, Notes Client is installed in my pc, accessing emails with my id and password. Fortunately, after restarted the kernel in Jupyter notebook it doesn't show the error now. But it does not show the folders or document from Inbox.

Comment: The name of the view is `($Inbox)`, not $Inbox

Comment: It's hard to help you when we do not know what is in the variables. I understand that you don't want to share the real names, but you could use fake names, but we could see the structure of the data and the special characters which are included in the servername and path

Comment: If it is a mail database, the path should start with mail/...